React-Native PencilKit: Strokes at the edges of canvasView flicker for a couple seconds when user draws after zooming in on canvas
Implemented iOS PencilKit for React-native with a native bridge. The canvasView's content area can be panned and zoomed.
However, I'm encountering a strange behavior...
When drawing in the content area while completely zoomed out (the canvas area is completely visible), the canvas drawing behaves perfectly fine.
However, when zoomed-in (so only a portion of the canvas is visible) and the user starts to draw, strokes at the lower and upper edges of the content area will flicker for a couple of seconds. Why does it do that?
Further, if I set the minimumZoomScale so that in effect it is like setting resizeMode = 'cover' for the content area (i.e. the content area covers the entire frame), it doesn't have that strange behavior. Doing this however, means user cannot view the entire content area on the screen at the same time.
- (UIView *)view {

  CGFloat deviceWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
  CGFloat deviceHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
  CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, deviceWidth, deviceHeight);
  _canvasView = [[CanvasView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

  _canvasView.zoomScale = 1.0; 
  _canvasView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.0]; 
  _canvasView.drawingPolicy = PKCanvasViewDrawingPolicyAnyInput;  
  _canvasView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
  _canvasView.multipleTouchEnabled = true;
  _canvasView.delegate = self;

  return _canvasView;
}


RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setupCanvas
                  : (nonnull NSNumber *)viewTag imagePath
                  : (NSString *)imagePath width
                  : (CGFloat)width height
                  : (CGFloat)height traceImagePath
                  : (NSString *)traceImagePath traceImageSize
                  : (nonnull NSNumber *)traceImageSize) {

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"Set Toolpicker");
    [self setupToolPicker];

    NSLog(@"Set Canvas size");
    [self setCanvasDimensions:width height:height];

    if (imagePath != (id)[NSNull null] && imagePath.length != 0) {
      NSLog(@"Draw on image");
      [self drawOnImage:imagePath];
    }

  
  });

}


- (void)setCanvasDimensions:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height {

  [self->_canvasView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];

  CGFloat canvasRepWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
  
  self->_canvasView.minimumZoomScale = canvasRepWidth 
  self->_canvasView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
  self->_canvasView.zoomScale = canvasRepWidth / width;
  self->_canvasView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

}



